# How to make Node.js listen to specific website and use AWS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, socket.io

So I'm kind of new to Node.js but i really want to host a website that uses Node.js in the background using Amazon Web Services (AWS). I am using Socket.io and Express.js with Node, and i have a html file with the client side code.

Here's part of each file:

server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("-- User Connected");
});

//express home page
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

//express listen on 8080
http.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Running...\nListening on port 8080");
});
```

index.html (Just the client-side javascript)

```
<script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on("connect", function() {
            console.log("connected");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything works great, but i was wondering how i would upload this to a AWS bucket and run it there. I already uploaded the full .html file to a AWS bucket and set up the host, so it opens and runs fine. But how would i go about uploading and running the server.js file? and what would i change in both the client side code (change io.connect() parameters?) and the server.js code (change .listen() to something?) so it runs with AWS?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Buckets are a feature of AWS' simple storage. They only support static files. You can't use them run server side side programs that you wrote yourself.

For that you'll need a different product, such as EC2.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Linux on Amazon EC2 instance. 
[Guide to get started with Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html).

Step 1: Create a Github/Bitbucket repository of your project so it can be easily cloned on the server. Private repo in GitHub are paid while in Bitbucket it's free under some conditions.

Step 2: SSH into the server. Clone the project. Install the required packages. Now you can run the node server on EC2 instance as you do on your localhost.

Step 3: AWS provides you with public DNS something like: `ec2-**-**-**-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com` Now access node server through `ec2-52-86-163-5.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/`

Step 4: To run the node app continuously you need something like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out... Do you know what i should change in the code though to make it work?

Comment: No. Working on EC2 is like creating a replica of your localhost. In order to run app endlessly, you need something like forever.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use S3 for hosting static websites as described in [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html).

If you would like to host your Node.js application on AWS I recommend that you use Elastic Beanstalk as explained in [Deploying Node.js Applications to AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html). The main difference compared to hosting the Node.js application on EC2 is that Beanstalk is a service that provides a runtime environment, i.e. you do not have to set up and manage the operatings system yourself. All you need to do is to package your application and upload it to Beanstalk. Consequently, a launch environment will be created and configured with the AWS resources needed to run your code.

For more information, please read [What Is AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)